# Using strict null checks, how can I generically assert not null where type is scoped down and error is thrown on failure?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
function assertNotFalsey<T>(test: T): void | never {
  if (!test) {
    throw new Error('your thing failed');
  }
}

function doesNotWork(possiblyNull: { id: string } | null) {
    // do something that makes me sure that possiblyNull.id exists unless there is a downnstream error
    assertNotFalsey(possiblyNull)
    console.log(possiblyNull.id) // Does not compile as `id` might be null
}

function doesWork(possiblyNull: { id: string } | null) {
    // do something that makes me sure that possiblyNull.id exists unless there is a downnstream error
    if (!possiblyNull) {
    throw new Error('your thing failed');
  }
    console.log(possiblyNull.id) // type is scoped down to not include null.
}
```

I would like to actually throw an error when asserting, not only tell the compiler to accept what I am doing by using the null assertion operator. If I could get the generic function to work, I could extend it to take an array of tests and print a specific error if any fail which would remove a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: There is a feature for this it is know as [assertion signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

Answer (score 0):

does this solve your problem

```
    console.log(possiblyNull?.id) // Does not compile as `id` might be null
```

Comment: I was hoping to scope down the type so that the developer does not have to keep track of what to override. I also do want the error to be triggered at runtime if the value is null in this case.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following

```
type HasId = {id: string}

//typegaurd to check for id
function checkId(obj:any) : obj is HasId{
 if(obj && typeof obj.id === "string"){return true;}
 throw new Error("checkID assertion failed")
}

function NowWorks<T extends HasId | null> (possiblyNull: T) {
  if (checkId(possiblyNull)) {
    console.log(possiblyNull.id) // Does not compile as `id` might be null
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwJIBMoF4oG8CWKBcUCwATjgHYDmAvgFC0D0DoklcAriWsAPZQDGACwj8A1lABmPElDy0J7cv2A4e5AcLGoAFDwBGAK3xxyIAJRRC+g7ISxEqLLVkTdhqADIPUFhB4SoawA6PAx0TAAiYjIqCLMsEghgTnVSdggAbjofQRIeAHcocghCgFESPJJtCKERUSQAEShEBAgSFTVJOBwAGwgUONo6eUVlVXUAOQKAdWlRBAAeABUoCAAPYAhyFDt4ZDQAHyL2Hp6APihtMB4EBBw9HpAJk57CJYsnKBdL2q0UK5udweTxeZg+zi+AjUCB4fSCPR4lABt3uj2epxCKAsTCgDR4EDs5B4wChAFswL1oIgoAADPA0qCknCUQQkvTQcgvCF0OhAA)